# How to upload .mobileconfig and txet file in amazon server in android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, file-upload

Hello friends i m trying to upload file or .mobileconfig in amazon server  , but  i m not able to upload file in amazon server , i can  upload the image in amazon server . Please friend help me how to upload the file in amazon server in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got the answer

```
        // Put the image data into S3.
        try {


            String bucketw = getPictureBucket();
            Log.d("ddddd", "bucketw :  " + bucketw);

            // Content type is determined by file extension.
            // PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(
            // getPictureBucket(), Constants.PICTURE_NAME,
            // new java.io.File(filePath));
            System.out.println(finammane);

            //
            String bucket = "vpnme";
            File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/vp.txt");
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream("/mnt/sdcard/vp.txt");

            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // you can configure the buffer
                                            // size
            while (in.read(buffer) != -1)
                out.write(buffer); // copy streams

            byte[] result2 = out.toByteArray();
            Long contentLength = Long.valueOf(result2.length);

            ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            metadata.setContentLength(contentLength);

            PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(getPictureBucket(),
                    finammane, new java.io.File("/mnt/sdcard/vp.txt")).withCannedAcl(
                    CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead).withMetadata(
                    metadata);
            s3Client.putObject(por);
            // Just set your directory
            // PutObjectRequest request = new
            // PutObjectRequest("my-unique-name",
            // "vpnme/" + Constants.PICTURE_BUCKET, file).withCannedAcl(
            // CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead).withMetadata(metadata);
            // s3Client.putObject(request);
            in.close();
            // buffer.

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("eeee" + exception);
            Log.d("e", "ee " + exception.getMessage());

            result.setErrorMessage(exception.getMessage());
        }
```